# Calling js function in external js file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a simple function with alert but it wont work when i try call the function (contained in an external js file) from my html page.

I have a import and the call is very simple. Any suggestions?

```
    <head>
<script src="/js/jsFunctions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my code I call

```
<a href="javascript:displayAlertText('someText');">
```

Inside the js I have some jquery followed by a function

```
function displayAlertText(someText)
    {
        alert('alert' + someText);
    }
```

Comment: make sure that the js-file really gets included. Put a alert('yes i am included'); into the js-file outside the displayAlertText-function,

Comment: Using a console debugger (like Web Developer Tools for IE8, or Firebug for Firefox would provide you with a meaningful error message, which you could post along with your code.

Comment: Maybe a file naming problem upper/lowercase on Linux/OSX?

Comment: yes have closing </a>, the file gets included, i can see it in firebug along with the method im trying to call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure jQuery you would do this like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(){
        alert('here');
    })

})
```

Comment: Unobtrusive is the way to go.
However, this will execute alert on every <a> element on the page.

If you add `class="some_class"` to `<a>` element, you could narrow it down to `<a>` elements with "some_class" `$('a.some_class')`.
Or if you add `id="some_id"` to `<a>` element, you narrow it down to one element identified by "some_id" (id's should be unique ofc) `$('a#some_id')`.

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing looks like it should work.  The problem is likely elsewhere.

Hrefs with "Javascript:" prefixes are really rather horrible.  Instead, try rewriting that as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayAlertText('someText'); return false;">
```

Beyond that (which I don't think would *actually* be causing it), you've committed the cardinal sin of saying "It didn't work".  Did you get any Javascript errors in the console?  I suspect you would have, unless a valid function really was called.

Also, try calling the JS function explicitly from within a `<script>` block on your page, to see at what point it's failing.

Double-check as well that the external file really has been loaded at the time you click on the link - perhaps put a line at the bottom of the external script file to help check this, such as

```
alert('External file loaded.');
```

**EDIT** (based on comment): OK, so we've established you can call the method from "normal" JavaScript on your page.  This means that the problem lies with the way that you're trying to call the script from your hyperlink.

Have you passed your HTML through a validator?  If the syntax is invalid, then user agents can interpret it however they want, including ignoring it completely.

If the HTML does validate then at this point it might be useful to post a link to your full HTML, so that others can look over it and see where the problem lies.  It's possibly something like another function overriding the `onclick` event for the link, and so your event handler gets lost.

Comment: thanks, when i call the function from a script block it works fine. also im using jquery functions from the external file and they all work fine. The only difference between the function that isint working and the jquery ones is taht it is defined outside the $(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 0):

try this instead...

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayAlertText('someText');">
```

If that does not help, I would start making sure that your javascript file is loading correctly and doesn't contains some simple syntax error somewhere. View your page with Firebug on in Firefox and look for warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned jQuery. Is the function standalone or inside a jQuery object (i.e. wrapped inside *another* function)? This makes difference.

**Apart** from this problem, the way you invoke the function isn't clean. Move it to the `onclick` attribute or better make use of jQuery.